# How to find index of particular value in loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file which I am storing in the data frame. The CSV files has a column 'Company name'.I want to create a new column and insert a value in this new column at a particular index where value for the company name is i

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('Some csv.csv')
df['New Column']= ' '
for  i in df['Company Name']: 
     found_list=[]

    for found, score, matchrow in process.extract(i, df['Company Name'], scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio):
        if score >= 75:
            print('%d%% partial match: "%s" with "%s" ' % (score, i, found))
            
            found_list.append(found)
    
    df['New Column'].index(i).append(found_list)  #I want to insert found list in 'New Column' corresponding to value i
```

But this gives error:

```
TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable
```

Comment: Hi Yash and welcome on SO. In pandas you should avoid loops as much as you can. Do you mind to have a look at [mcve](/help/mcve) and [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @rpanai, thank you. Well, I am using loops because I have to pass in every value of the column 'Company Name' to process.extract(). There may be another approach, but to tell you I am just a beginner, wanting to learn efficient and better ways.

Comment: i think that you can make a function and use `apply`.

Comment: @rpanai, What about the index?

Comment: Please try to make a toy example of your dataframe and I'll show you the details

Comment: @rpanai, I am sorry but I do not understand the toy example

Comment: ii hope this is what you mean: df=pd.DataFrame({'Company name':['abc','bcd','efg','hij']})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below approach to append values in a new column -

```
dataframe['new_col'] = np.nan
for i in range(0, len(dataframe)):
    var = 1600
    dataframe.set_value(i, 'new_col', var)
```

Instead of dataframe.set_value(i, 'new_col', var), you can use:
dataframe.at[i, 'new_col'] = var

because dataframe.set_value() is depreciated.

You can refer to the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html

Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: @kantar, this seems to work but. I have a list of lists. I can't seem to understand why is it only populating the last value of list in all the columns

Comment: Do you want to update each column with each list from the list of lists?

Comment: If final list is your list of lists then do you wish to populate each list in each of the column? Let's say you have list of 3 lists with each list of equal length, then do you want that each column will get populated with each list?                                             I would suggest that first you create a column and fill it with nan e.g. df['new_col'] = np.nan later populate each value corresponding to row column with a desired value, which can be picked from  list.